# Can I use $ at beginning of variable name or enum symbol in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

As title. For example:

```
enum MyEnum {
  case $SYMBOL
}

let $foo = MyEnum.$SYMBOL
```

I get `error: expected numeric value following '$'`.

Interestingly, $ can be used in middle of variable name. Is there a list of symbols we can use at beginning?

#### Justification:

According to Apple's language guide ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)):

> Constant and variable names cannot contain whitespace characters, mathematical symbols, arrows, private-use (or invalid) Unicode code points, or line- and box-drawing characters. Nor can they begin with a number, although numbers may be included elsewhere within the name.

Dollar sign is not forbidden.

However, the [Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) section does mention the use of `$0`, `$1` as Shorthand Argument Names:

> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.

which reserves the use of dollar sign at beginning. This contradicts the previous rule.

The Xcode Playground further complicate the situation. If I create a Swift playground file and paste my code, the variable will be evaluated as a `(Enum Value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use $ at beginning of variable name or enum symbol in Swift?

**No.** If you look at the [Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html) section under "Grammar of an Identifier," you'll see a list of all the ranges of characters that are allowed as *identifier_head*. `$`, or `U+0024`, is not included in the list.

If you dig a little further, you'll find that an *enum-case-name* is an *identifier* and a *variable-name* is also an *identifier*, so the grammar for identifiers governs what's allowed.

> Dollar sign is not forbidden.

It seems that the list of "forbidden" characters in the section you linked is not exhaustive. It's not hard to come up with a number of characters not listed there that are nevertheless not listed in the grammar: `@`, `#`, `?`...

> Can you explain why my code does not fail in playground? Does playground get special treatment?

It's probably a bug -- just a case where the playground is slightly more permissive.

Comment: Can you explain why my code does not fail in playground? Does playground get special treatment?